# How to find last day of previous month in excel without using EOMONTH

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using apache poi to read data from excel. My excel contains date for which I am using different formula such as Now(),Now()-7,EOMONTH() etc

POI does not have implementaion for EOMONTH so it fails to read the cell. Is there workaround for EOMOnth in excel which i can use.
I have to basically enter first or last day or this month, prev month and 2 months older.
For this month I am using DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1)
but not able to write for prev month. 
Any help please.

Thanks,
Pratik

Comment: Got it.. Posting it incase someone is interested DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1)-1

Comment: If you're able to code it up, POI happily accepts [contributions](http://poi.apache.org/guidelines.html), and formula functions are fairly easy to write!

Comment: Getting EOM is potentially not the best way to handle things; with most types of ranges, you want the upper-bound to be exclusive (`<`).  With date ranges, depending on the precision allowed, you end up running into the problems detailed in [this blog post](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (SQL Server just has some additional gotchas, but the essential problem is the same for _all_ variable-precision ranges, such as decimal types).  I'd stick with first-of-month values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

end of last month: `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),1) - 1`

end of this month: `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,1) - 1`

one month earlier: `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())-1,DAY(NOW()))`

one month later: `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())+1,DAY(NOW()))`

Comment: You can get some odd results with some of those towards the end of the month, e.g. if you use this one: `=DATE(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW())-1,DAY(NOW()))` on 31st March 2014 the result is 3rd March 2014!

Comment: indeed ... when this mont has 31 days and last month has 28, 29, or 30 days, then for month-1, 31 there is an issue ... thinking ...

Answer (score 2):

You can get 1st of this month with this formula

`=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())+1`

and last day of last month by just removing the +1, i.e.

`=TODAY()-DAY(TODAY())`

Last day of this month can be

`=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY())+1,0)`

Comment: yeep - that's better. @pratik I propose to accept this one rather than mine.